# iOS 6 contacts access alert never showed on debug

Tags: debugging, permissions, ios6, contacts

My app on the appstore is accessing the iPhone contacts, after the users downloaded it on iOS 6 it can't access the iPhone contacts while its working fine on iOS 5
the problem is the new privacy settings apple has put in iOS 6 .. so after searching i found out that i have to do the following in my code to be able to access the user contacts:

```
    //in order to test addressbook availability we have to attempt to create an addressbook instance using ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000

    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef,
                                                 ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                                                     if (granted)
                                                         [self loadContacts];
                                                 });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        [self loadContact];
    } else {

    }

#endif //end iOS6+

    //ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions not available or succeeded. return YES;
    [self loadContacts];
```

My problem now is while debugging on the device, the alert is not showing, i don't know why ?
I know that the above code should work fine, but only when the app is submitted to the appstore but i want to test that in debug mode before submission ?
Any advice ?

Appreciate your support.
Thanks.

Comment: ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus is Always kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized even if the app is running for the first time !!!!

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to get it resolved
Here is the new code after a slight modification:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000

    __block MyClassType *controller = self;

    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef,
                                                 ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                                                     if (granted)
                                                         [controller loadContacts];
                                                 });
    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        [self loadContacts];
    } else {

    }

#else
    [self loadContacts];
#endif
```

The key to be able to test it is to Reset the Privacy and location settings from Settings>>General>>Reset>>Reset Location & Privacy

It worked fine with me.

Comment: I was thinking its because of debugging but it has nothing to do with debugging you just have to reset the privacy settings :)

Comment: Reseting the privacy settings did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

Resetting Location & Privacy doesn't work for me.

My authorization status is always kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized, regardless of whether I clear simulator settings and then reset Location and Privacy.